# Automapper: Update property values without creating a new object

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

How can I use automapper to update the properties values of another object without creating a new one?

Answer (score 612, accepted):

Use the overload that takes the existing destination:

```
Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination);
```

Yes, it returns the destination object, but that's just for some other obscure scenarios.  It's the same object.

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy...I purposely stayed away from AutoMapper because I was afraid of the learning curve impacting my schedule. I'm officially sorry I stayed away so long...it's much easier than I initially thought.

Comment: Automapper has to be one of the most useful libraries out there.  I too avoided it for a long time, much too long.  I started using it today and am very surprised at how easy it is to use.

Comment: Not work for me. I try to map to same type, but it's return new object.
User u1, u3 = new User();
u1 = new User
{
  Id = 1,
  NickName = "vami"
};

User u4 = Mapper.Map(u1, u3);

Assert.AreEqual(u1.Id, u3.Id);
Assert.AreEqual(u1.NickName, u3.NickName);

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get an error asking for constructor but it should not need one if it is mapping to an existing object... See this article. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099405/automapper-not-copying-from-source-to-destination-object-correctly-errors-nee#

Comment: FYI, I discovered you don't need to specify the type parameters. Simply, Mapper.Map(source, destination) will work. Nice and simple!

Comment: Has the NULL behaviour changed in release 4.2.1?  I'm seeing that mapping null into an object returns null; whereas in 2.2.1, mapping null into an existing object returned the existing object.

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy maybe. I have hundreds of tests but I can't cover every scenario.

Comment: @Péter, I have reproduced it but corrected by adding cfg.CreateMap<User, User>();

Comment: @JimmyBogard, Peter's issue I have corrected by using "self-refering" CreateMap. BTW. I was used to have exception in situation that I don't have a mapping configured but this time AutoMapper silently does nothing.

Comment: @AndrzejMartyna hmm, I was trying to do that with `IEnumerable<>`, but I just noticed the **self-refering** solution only works for individual entities. Well, a `foreach` solved my situation, but I wonder why using `IEnumerable<>` doesn't work.

Comment: @JimmyBogard How can I propagate this behavior down to the properties being mapped? For example, Say I have a class Foo with a reference to a class Bar. I want the fields of Foo.Bar to be updated with the values of the source's Foo.Bar. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It creates a new object. In my case I obtain an entity from the db, then apply a model to it. It overwrites all the field with defaults. In my case the model doesn't have a date value where as the entity does. When I map model->entity, the date goes to it's default value.

Comment: This could be simplified to: `Mapper.Map(source, destination)`

Comment: Hi guys, This solution works for main object, but if this main object has nested objects we will have the same problem. .MapFrom() will be overwritte the nested object).Does anyone know how to avoid this same problem in nested objects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688688/autommaper-overwrite-the-value-of-nested-object

Answer (score 42):

To make this work you have to CreateMap for types of source and destination even they are same type.
That means if you want to 
`Mapper.Map<User, User>(user1, user2);`
You need to create map like this
`Mapper.Create<User, User>()`

Comment: Ha! I've just found the same and added a comment to the accepted answer.

IMHO the accepted answer without your explanation is not complete but after my comment it might be, finally :)

Comment: This is a great addition. However, the original question did not mention the types of the source and destination, and did not require that they be the same type.

Comment: This was the issue for me, too. Had to create a profile that maps A to A and then it worked.

Answer (score 12):

If you wish to use an instance method of IMapper, rather than the static method used in the accepted answer, you can do the following (tested in `AutoMapper 6.2.2`)

```
IMapper _mapper;
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
});
_mapper = config.CreateMapper();

Source src = new Source
{
//initialize properties
}

Destination dest = new dest
{
//initialize properties
}
_mapper.Map(src, dest);
```

`dest` will now be updated with all the property values from `src` that it shared. The values of its unique properties will remain the same.

[Here's the relevant source code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/894412e72e98cb0d6da957b5a5be52f888fc6cd5/src/AutoMapper/IMapper.cs#L45)

Answer (score 0):

There's two things to note here. First, we don't have to specify the type to map to for the generic Map call. This is because, now, we're passing the destination object instance, so the destination type can be determined by the type of that object. Second, we're not storing the result of this call in a variable. This is because the destination object is mapped to in place and we're not creating any new instances.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(sourceObject, destinationObject);
```