# Automapper - Not copying from source to destination object correctly. Errors need default constructor

Tags: c#, automapper-3

When I map a source object into an existing instance it appears to want to create a new object  and not copy into...

Here is my test scenario:

```
List<DomainCustomerProxy> domainCustomers = customers.Select(customer => new DomainCustomerProxy(
                new Lazy<List<DomainContact>>(() => RetrieveContactsByCustomerId(customer.Id, lazyLoad, schemaName).ToList(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
                new Lazy<List<DomainDepartment>>(() => RetrieveDepartmentsByCustomerId(customer.Id, lazyLoad, schemaName).ToList(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication),
                new Lazy<List<DomainGroup>>(() => RetrieveCustomerGroupsByCustomerId(customer.Id, lazyLoad, schemaName).ToList(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
                    )
            {
                Id = customer.Id,
            }).ToList();

            domainCustomers = Mapper.Map(customers, domainCustomers);

            return domainCustomers;
```

I get this error:
Type 'Raven.Lib.Domain.CRM.Models.CustomerProxy' does not have a default constructor

```
public class CustomerProxy : Customer
{
    public CustomerProxy(Lazy<List<Contact>> contacts, Lazy<List<Department>> departments, Lazy<List<Group>> groups)
    {
        _contactLazyList = contacts;
        _departmentLazyList = departments;
        _groupLazyList = groups;
    }

    private readonly Lazy<List<Contact>> _contactLazyList;
    public override List<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get { return _contactLazyList.Value; }
    }

    private readonly Lazy<List<Department>>_departmentLazyList;
    public override List<Department> Departments 
    { 
        get { return _departmentLazyList.Value; } 
    }

    private readonly Lazy<List<Group>> _groupLazyList;
    public override List<Group> CustomerGroups
    {
        get { return _groupLazyList.Value; }
    }
}
```

customer base class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; private set; }
    public int ModifiedById { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; private set; }
    public int Version { get; private set; }

    public virtual List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Group> CustomerGroups { get; set; }

    public SerializableDictionary<string, string> ValidationErrors { get; set; }

    public bool Validate()
    {
        ValidationErrors = new SerializableDictionary<string, string>();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            ValidationErrors.Add(LambdaHelper<Customer>.GetPropertyName(x => x.Name), "Customer.Name is a mandatory field.");
        }

        if (Number <= 0)
        {
            ValidationErrors.Add(LambdaHelper<Customer>.GetPropertyName(x => x.Number), "Customer.Number is a mandatory field and can not be 0.");
        }

        return ValidationErrors.Count > 0;
    }
}
```

Now if I create a empty default constructor

```
protected CustomerProxy(){ }
```

It does not error but the appears to wipe out my old instance here is the proof.

Mapping ignoring the properties I dont want overwritten.

```
    CreateMap<DaoCustomer, DomainCustomerProxy>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerGroups, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Departments, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ValidationErrors, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Before:
[image]
After:
[image]

Am I using automapper incorrectly?
domainCustomers = Mapper.Map(customers, domainCustomers);

Little back ground:
I am using the virtual proxy pattern for lazy loading my contacts,departments, and groups as these are very large lists. This is why I inherit from Customer which is the base class.

Comment: Post the parameterless constructor please.

Comment: If your Properties have no public setter, how will any mapper, automatic or not, be able to set them?

Comment: @Ufuk The constructor is added it does nothing.  But why is it needed if it is mapped to a instance that already exists?

Comment: @oerkelens you are correct I did not have the base class of customer in the code above. They have public setters. I have added that now.  This is the properties that I want set from automapper.