# C# Combine data of two classes into one of those classes

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a entity class that is populated from the backend and then automapper is used to map the data to a new DTO Model.  I have other data coming in from another source that has some same data and new data that i want placed into the DTO.  When i say same data, I mean, some properties of the new source should overwrite properties in the dto that already have data in them.

Is there a way to use automapper or some nice easy way to merge this data?  or is the only way to do this by manual mapping?

Thanks

Comment: I think its not good approach. You should create new DTO everytime when you need modify data. IMHO Composing DTO during life time its bad.

Comment: i need to combine the values because a processor that is finally called takes a single model that needs data from multiple sources overwritten in a particular order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: Update property values without creating a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object)

Comment: @Progman tx. i think you are right. will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var model = Mapper.Map<Model>(dto1);
Mapper.Map(dto2, model);
```