# Automapper: To do an update on existing entity object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, automapper

I want to **update** an existing entity object from another model. But each time I got a new object (Having the mapped properties and default values for other properties.) Instead, I want a partially updated destination object.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Customer, MYPOCO>().ReverseMap());


public void UpdateEntity(Customer customerSrc)
{
    MYPOCO pocoDesc= dbContext.DD_POCO.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == 123);
    pocoDesc = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customer, MYPOCO>(customerSrc, pocoDesc);

  // Here "pocoDesc" is a new object, I got only "customerSrc" data and lost all other existing properties values.
}
```

Automapper: 6.2.2(version)

Tried [Automapper: Update property values without creating a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object)

Any Idea?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: Update property values without creating a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object)

Comment: You are using the correct `Map` overload, so your `pocoDesc` should be the same instance obtained by the `SingleOrDefault` call. Are you sure `SingleOrDefault` doesn't return `null`? How aboiut changing it to `Single`?

Comment: SingleOrDefault returns correct data,  not null

Comment: @IvanStoev Tried with Single but not getting updated object

Comment: It was just to prove the destination entity is not `null`. Honestly it's hard to believe the above code does not update the existing object. I'm doing this all the time and it works as expected, do you have a full repro? Or in other words, is to posted code complete or there is something not shown there?

Comment: It's probably not a new object. Have you tried assigning it to a different variable and checking for reference equality?

Answer (score 5):

if it still issue, try the following :

```
public void UpdateEntity(Customer customerSrc)
{
    MYPOCO pocoDesc= dbContext.DD_POCO.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == 123);
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Customer, MYPOCO>(customerSrc, pocoDesc);
    dbContext.DD_POCO.Update(pocoDesc);
    dbContext.Save();
}
```