# How to use Automapper to map to (and from) multiple destinations from a single model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

Say I have the following related entities with one-to-one relationships:

```
public class A {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}

    public virtual B B {get; set;}
    public virtual int BId {get; set;}
}


public class B {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    public virtual A A {get; set;}
    public virtual int AId {get; set;}
}
```

And the single class (DTO) that will contain the fields for both these classes:

```
public class C {
    public int Id {get; set;} //which will correspond to AId
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}
```

How do I map from `class C` to `class A` and `B` using Automapper? 
When I use the following, it says that the navigation properties (`B` for `class A`, and `A` for `class B`) are null:

```
CreateMap<C, A>().ReverseMap();
CreateMap<C, B>()
    .ForMember(b => b.AId, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Id))
    .ReverseMap();
```

And when I try to call a `Mapper.Map` function inside `CreateMap` it yields an error where Mapper must be initialized first. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about this?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object

Comment: Create 2 mapping profiles. From A to C and from B to C. Then first let an instance of A map to C. After that map an instance of B to C but passing the instance of C that was created with the A-to-C mapping

Comment: Oh, I see! Didn't think of updating the current instance already created, and I didn't know there was an overload for it. Thank you very much!