# C# Automap properties to an array

Tags: c#, automapper

I have lists of two separate Models that I need to merge into a parent Model that is also a list. For example:

**Child model 1**:

```
public class Sweet 
{
  public int SweetLevel {get; set;}
  public bool IsSweet {get; set;}
}
```

**Child model 2**:

```
public class Spicy
{
  public int IsSpicy {get; set;}
  public bool SpiceLevel {get; set;}
}
```

**Parent model** that I am trying to merge child model 1&2 into.

```
public class FoodItem 
{
  public int SweetLevel {get; set;}
  public bool IsSweet {get; set;}
  public bool IsSpicy {get; set;}
  public int SpiceLevel {get; set;}
}
```

---

Here is how I am trying to map the list of spicy items, and the list of sweet items to the parent FoodItem.

```
List<Sweet> listOfSweetItems = GetListOfSweetItems();
List<Spicy> listOfSpicyItems = GetListOfSpicyItems();

// Map the Sweet items
var mappedSweetItems = Mapper.Map<List<FoodItem>>(listOfSweetItems); // this maps correctly
// Map the Spicy items
var mappedSpicyItems = Mapper.Map<List<FoodItem>>(listOfSpicyItems); // this maps correctly
```

These work independently, but I want to map them into the same FoodItem object at the same time so that after one iteration it would look something like:

```
[{
 SweetLevel: 5,
 IsSweet: true,
 SpicyLevel: 1,
 IsSpicy: false
} , ...]
```

How can I map my `Sweet` and `Spicy` models into the parent `FoodItem` model at the same time?

Comment: `Mapper.Map` has an overload to update an existing object. That might work for you here. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
     config.CreateMap<Sweet, FoodItem>()
        .ForMember(f => f.IsSpicy, o => o.Ignore())
        .ForMember(f => f.SpiceLevel, o => o.Ignore());
     config.CreateMap<Spicy, FoodItem>()
        .ForMember(f => f.IsSweet, o => o.Ignore())
        .ForMember(f => f.SweetLevel, o => o.Ignore());
});
// ...
var foodItems = Mapper.Map<List<FoodItem>>(listOfSweetItems);
foodItems = foodItems
   .Zip(listOfSpicyItems, (foodItem, spicyItem) => Mapper.Map(spicyItem, foodItem))
   .ToList();
```

Hope it helps!