# AutoMapper setting EF entity ID to 0 during mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have a `Character` entity and a `CharacterDto` as follows:

**Character**

```
public class Character
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Health { get; set; } = 100;
    public int Defense { get; set; } = 10;
    public int Strength { get; set; } = 10;
    public int Intelligence { get; set; } = 10;
    public RpgClass Class { get; set; }
}
```

**CharacterDto**

```
public class CharacterDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public int Defense { get; set; }
    public int Strength { get; set; }
    public int Intelligence { get; set; }
    public RpgClass Class { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `CharacterMappingProfile` class which configures my `Character` and `DTO` mappings:

```
CreateMap<CharacterDto, Character>()
  .ForMember(
    dest => dest.Id,
    opt => opt.Ignore()
  );
```

I am attempting to map the values present in a `CharacterDto` onto an existing `Character` entity I have retried from a database using EntityFramework.

```
var character = _context.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
character = _mapper.Map<Character>(dto);
```

Prior to performing the map, `character` has a valid `Id` property. However, after the map the value is `0` which is not what I want. I would like AutoMapper to ignore that property and for it to therefore remain whatever the value is from the database. I must be misunderstanding how the `ForMember` with `Ignore` works as I thought that would do the trick.

Have I configured my mapping incorrectly or am I going wrong elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map a `CharacterDto` to an existing `Character` object you need to use:

```
var character = _context.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...);
_mapper.Map(dto, character);
```

Right now `_mapper.Map<Character>(dto);` is mapping your dto to a new empty `Character` instance and then you are assigning it to the character variable. That's why `Id` property is 0.

[Automapper: Update property values without creating a new object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374689/automapper-update-property-values-without-creating-a-new-object)

Comment: Thanks, `_mapper.Map(dto, character);` solved it. I had tried providing the existing `Character` as a second parameter in the `Map` function, but not without `<T>`.