# how to use automapper in update method cqrs pattern

Tags: asp.net, .net, automapper, cqrs

When I want to update an entity, I face the following error:

```
Message = "The instance of entity type 'Vehicle' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Conside...
```

I have added the database as addScope. I think the problem is during Mapping because when I manually fill the Entity fields with the sent request, it works without any problem.
My question is how to map the properties? Each of my Entity has a lot of properties and it is difficult to manually enter all these working values.

Update method:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateVehicle(UpdateVehicleCommand command)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(command.Id))
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        try
        {
            var result = await Mediator.Send(command);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Can not Update Vehicle because : {e}", e.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

in UpdateVehicleCommand :

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(UpdateVehicleCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = await _context.Vehicles
            .FindAsync(new object[] { request.Id }, cancellationToken);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Vehicle), request.Id);
        }

        
         // *********** Mapping ****************
         // ****The problem is in the following line****
        _context.Vehicles.Update(_mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.Vehicle.Vehicle>(request));



        ***********Import in manual mode************
        //entity.ImageDocument = request.ImageDocument;
        //entity.ImageFrontCard = request.ImageFrontCard;
        //entity.ImageBackCard = request.ImageBackCard;
        .....
        .....
        .....
        

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
```

Profile settings for automapper are also added correctly

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with Automapper and EF is doing what you are telling it to do, which is not correct:

> var entity = await _context.Vehicles
> .FindAsync(new object[] { request.Id }, cancellationToken);

This loads an entity with Id equal to `request.Id` into the Context.

> _context.Vehicles.Update(_mapper.Map<Domain.Entities.Vehicle.Vehicle>(request));

And this line attaches a new entity with the same id to the context. Therefore, EF complains that there is already one entity with that Id.

There are multiple ways to implement this. I can give you a couple:

1. Instead of loading the entity, just check if it exists, for example with AnyAsync(). If it returns `false`, throw an exception.
2. Load the entity as you do now, but instead of attaching a new entity (with the Update method), [use automapper to map the values from the request to the `entity` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376102/352826) that you loaded. There is no need to call `context.Vehicles.Update` because the entity is already being tracked by EF. If you change any property and then call `context.SaveChangesAsync`, the changes will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the main reasons I dislike Entity Framework for RESTful API development:  The Unit Of Work pattern is not for the majority of your needs when programming REST.  You are being bitten by one of the so-called "features" of Entity Framework:  Entity tracking.  I don't think I can tell you exactly where your problem is because it is actually dependant on the workflow your server follows, but I can give you the general rule of thumb:  Disable tracking for your `DbSet<>`'s whenever you are getting data.

As for a long-term solution:  Dump EF.  Move to Dapper, even if only for querying.